# Generics, companion object, and inheritance in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, inheritance, companion-object

I'm working with ViewBindings on Android, with code generated by the compiler from the xml that must look like that

```kotlin
class ViewBinding {...}

class MyBinding : ViewBinding {
    companion object {
        fun inflate (...) { 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid copy/pasting code, I want to create a class, accepting a class child of ViewBinding as a generic type argument, and with a companion object having the method inflate.

```kotlin
class MyClass<T:ViewBinding having the method inflate in the companion object of the class> { ... }
```

What's the smartest way to do that ?

Comment: Need more detail about what you're trying to do. What is MyClass? A subclass of your ViewBinding, some kind of wrapper for your ViewBinding, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is, what you're trying to do is impossible. The type parameter restrictions apply on the type itself, not its companion object, which isn't actually related to the class (it gets compiled as a separate class with no relation with the original class). The Java equivalent, implementing a static method from an interface, also isn't possible.

What you could do however, is to use the companion itself as a type parameter, the companion implementing an interface with the `inflate` method:

```kotlin
interface ViewBindingCompanion {
    fun inflate(): ViewBinding
}

class MyBinding : ViewBinding {
    companion object : ViewBindingCompanion {
        fun inflate(): ViewBinding { 
            ...
        }
    }
}

class MyClass<T : ViewBindingCompanion>
```

And then:

```kotlin
MyClass<MyBinding.Companion>()
```

Leave a comment if I missed something.

Comment: I will absolutely try that, that's a clever way to solve the problem if it works ! tyvm